# Can disable a Windows Vista Check disk on boot for unknown volume

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning

I'm unable to find out why my Windows always wants to check a volume that I can't determine.
Here is a crappy snapshot with my cellular

[image: Photo of screen showing the problem]

I can read \?\volume{73....

Of course I can't use `chkdsk -x [DRIVE]` because it is not a drive.

Answer (score 1):

Checkdisk works fine with volume mount points, i.e. instead of the drive letter you can specify:

chkdsk \?\Volume{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX} /f /x